# Visual Studio Code does not allow me to implement my interface(Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, interface

I have a project with two java files. One is the class withe the main-method and the other is a interface with two methods, which is impelemented in the Java-class and I did override the functions there.

This is my Code from the Java-Class:

```
public class Point implements Compare {

int y;
int x;

public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void setX (int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY (int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public boolean isEqualTo(Point x) {
    if ((this.x == x.getX()) && (this.y == x.getY()))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

public boolean isSmallerThan(Point x) {
    if (this.x < x.getX())
        return true;
    else if (this.y < x.getY())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

}

And this is the Code from my Interface:

```
public interface Compare {

public boolean isEqualTo();
public boolean isSmallerThan();
}
```

When I try to run the code i always get the following error:

```
Point.java:1: error: Point is not abstract and does not override abstract method isSmallerThan() in Compare

public class Point implements Compare {
   ^

1 error
```

The strange thing is now, that the same code works when i write it in project in IntelliJ IDEA.
I havent found anything on the internet yet.
ah, and i work on macOS.
Hopefully anybody can help, why the code doesnt work in VSC.
Thanks

Comment: The methods in your interface don't take parameters. The methods in your class do. Therefore the class is not implementing the interface, as those methods are not the same.

Comment: Thank you now its working :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not Visual Studio Code. It's a Java compiler.
It tells you "If you declared interface methods and then implementing class with this interface you have to implement them or use [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). The method signature should be the same."